# A word for "when you are looking at somebody but thinking something else"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "when you are looking at somebody but thinking something else"?

Like when you stare at somebody but you are thinking of something else.

Comment: Are talking about a *blank stare" or a "vacant expression" or perhaps a "far-away look"?

Comment: @Jim I'm referring to a "blank stare", if there are apt words for the rest of the cases, can you tell me those too?

Comment: *Absent minded*; *inattentive*; *oblivious*; *preoccupied.*

Comment: "He's elsewhere."

Comment: `Day-Dreaming` and `Lost-in-Thoughts` can fit the bill. There is also the standard expression `Looking London, Talking Tokyo` for those suffering from medical condition of strabismus or cross-eyed syndrome.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne Another expression that comes to mind is - *Physically present, mentally absent (or somewhere else)*.

Comment: Like that much missed TV show, *lost in space*.

Comment: @Prahlad Yeri - +1 for, "Looking London, Talking Tokyo" Love it, never heard before.

Comment: Well, you could probably be said to be "day dreaming".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you’re describing the old “thousand mile stare", which usually happens to me when I am preoccupied by something weighing heavily on my mind, or when a strong or vivid memory suddenly seizes my attention.

> **Thousand Mile Stare**
>
> To stare blankly while deeply in thought as if you were looking a thousand miles away. 
>   Usually brought on by a stressful event or situation, causing one to block out their surroundings and stare off into nothing.  See the Urban Dictionary [**Thousand Mile Stare**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Thousand+Mile+Stare)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context of the sentence, and from whose point of view it is.

From the perspective of the viewer, you could say that the person was *inadvertently* staring at the other person, or was *unawares*.

The person being looked at could use the idiom *he/she looked right through me*.

Answer (score 0):

I think absent-minded would fit.

Answer (score 0):

The slang expressions "zoned out" or "spaced out" are pretty close to this, e.g.

> "Why are you staring at me?"
>
> "Oh, sorry, I was zoning out."